# How can I use get query in jinja while doing a django project?

Tags: jinja2

So I am doing a django project. I have sent a dictionary(which holds a foreign key) to my html template. It has 'name'(which is a foreignkey),'bills','flat' keys. So when I am trying to print the name of a user it is actually printing the id of the user. But I want the name. I have used `users = User.objects.all().values('name','bills','flat')` and then passed the users in the template. The I tried to print like this:
`{% for info in users %} {{info}} {% endfor %}`
But instead of giving the name it is giving me the id number of the user.

My models.py file:

```
`
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Payment(models.Model):
    name=models.ForeignKey(Owner,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    flat = models.CharField(max_length=1,null=True,blank=True)
    floor = models.IntegerField(default=0)`
```

My views.py file:
`

```
info = Payment.objects.all()
dict = {'1':[info.values('name','flat','floor','water_bill')]}
```

`

My Template file:

```
`
{% for j in dict.0 %}
<tr>
{% for i in j.values %}
<td>{{i}}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
`
```

Comment: Kindly share the python code that you have used.

Comment: can you check the post now?

Comment: In your views.py file, how do you call the html file? Do you use statement like the following, ```return render_template(template)```

Comment: I wrote `return render(request,'file.html',{'dict':dict})`

Answer (score 0):

The return statement should look something like this,

```
return render_template(file.html, dict = dict)
```

Then you can use the dict variable in jinja as follows,

```
{% for j,k in dict %}
<tr>
{% for i in j.values %}
<td>{{i}}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: actually I wanted to know how I am gonna get the name from the id. `info.values('name','flat','floor','water_bill')` here I want to print the name instead of the id. The name here is a foreign key of another table. So instead of printing the name it is printing the id. So is there any way so that I can print the name but not the id?